# Get notified when user jumps to a marker (annotation) in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm currently writing a plugin for the Eclipse IDE. In this plugin, I defined my own type of resource marker (IMarker). Using the standard Eclipse means like the "Next annotation"/"Previous annotation" buttons, the user has the possibility to navigate between these markers. I also wrote a view which shows some detail information for a single marker. This view shall be updated when the user navigates to a marker. Can I register some kind of listener/observer that will be notified when the user selects/jumps to a marker? If so, how? If not, what are my alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Next Annotation action ends up calling the `ITextEditorExtension4.gotAnnotation` method. The usually implementation for this is in `AbstractTextEditor`. This just calls finds the annotation and calls the `selectAndReveal` method.

So there does not seem to be any special listener you can use for this. Normal selection events should be generated so you could use the `ISelectionService` selection listener but you will have to work out if the selection is for your marker.

Comment: This does not seem to work the way I want it to. I get events this way, but they are of type `TextSelection`, and I did not find a way to tell whether this is caused by "user jumped to marker" or by some other type of selection change.

Comment: There is no way that you can tell, as far as I can see this is the best that can be done.